# How do I ensure Firebase database structure using anonymous auth?

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, geojson, firebase-security

I have a public-input type app using Firebase, with anonymous auth. The user data is used to create points on a map. Each anonymous user can only edit the data inside the node matching their auth id - via security rules.

However, my app depends on a certain database structure. How do I ensure my database structure/integrity using anonymous auth, since the database url is client-side readable?

I think it is possible with security and validation rules, but I'm not sure. Maybe deny children creation in a node? This would be necessary to ensure the schema is followed.

Each auth node can have many key nodes, but I would want to limit this Firebase-side. And each key node must follow the schema below (so I can pull out the geojson easily). Below is my current setup - wondering what is missing?

```
"features" : {
    "5AGxfaK2q8hjJsmsO3PUxUs09Sz1" : {
      "-KS3R4sWPdcDkrxyIFX6" : {
        "geometry" : {
          "coordinates" : [ -81.88247680664062, 38.884619201291905 ],
          "type" : "Point"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "color" : "#2be",
          "title" : ""
        },
        "type" : "Feature"
      },
```

[image: firebase rules]

Comment: You might find the bolt compiler useful. It lets you define types and can make defining a schema using the security rules a little easier. See: https://github.com/firebase/bolt

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: The pic is a lot easier to read, but I can include the actual data, sure. I'll update soon.

Comment: Also, looks like 
    "$other": {".validate": "false"}
could be useful here, from the bolt examples.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication and database schema are completely separate topics. You ensure database schema by using a combination of `.write` and `.validate` rules in your security doc, not by anything to do with your authentication provider (i.e. Anonymous authentication).

This is described in detail in our [database security guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

A quick summary:

- `hasChildren`: specify required fields
- `newData`: refer to the data being written
- `data`: refer to data already in the database
- `.validate`: specify data schema using things like `newData.isString()` or `newData.val() == data.val() + 1`

Keep in mind that `.validate` rules are only run for non-null values. Thus, if you want to try something like `!data.exists()` (i.e. you can only write to this path once and can't modify it later) or `newData.exists()` (i.e. you can't delete this data) then you need to specify those in a `.write` rule.

Refer to the guide for more detail.

Comment: Well, if you use a login-type auth, then there are Oauth redirect domains, but from the older firebase docs, it seems anonymous auth is not included. You could argue that an ssl domain could be spoofed, but disregarding that, for cases where Oath redirect domains are used, rules could be assigned client-side in javascript, correct?

Comment: Does hasChildren return false if the newData has more children than is specified? Or do I have to use the "$other": {".validate": "false"} as described above?